# Восстановление репозиториев Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Суть проблемы: 
На сервере Gitlab не делались бэкапы. Сервер полетел. Последняя копия была 2 месяца назад. Сервер восстановлен из неё, но изменения за последние 2 месяца утеряны. Новые репозитории не создавались, а старые не удалялись. Но есть критические изменения.

Информация есть в локальных репозиториях. Есть ли способ восстановить все данные (включая ветки) из локальных репозиториев в удалённый?

Comment: Ну, сделать git push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть способ. Удаленный репозиторий это тот же самый локальный репозиторий, только на другом компьютере. Можно тупо скопировать файловым менеджером, можно сделать `git push`.

Comment: Таким образом восстановятся в том числе и ветки?

Comment: @alexerem17 `git push --all` тогда запушатся все ветки